# Calculate views distance from top inside a recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recently been trying to implement a calendar day view (see picture) with items laying on top of a recycler view

[Example of part of the calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3rI.png)

Currently I calculate the offset the item needs to have from the top of the recycler view with this bit of code

```
val dpPerMinute = 24f / 15f
val viewOffset = 12f
initialOffset = (startTime * dpPerMinute + viewOffset + 4f).dpToPx().toInt()
```

The background item height is 24dp and is equal to 15 minutes, viewOffset is just to offset the view to the center of the itemHeight and the 4 comes from padding

Whenever I scroll in the view I update the position of the item with this

```
val pos = -offset + initialOffset
view?.translationY = pos.toFloat()
```

Offset is the recycler views current scroll Y and initialOffset is calculated above

This works great on my Samsung, everything lines up perfectly. But then comes the problem, I tested it on another work phone (as we do, a OnePlus Nord) and now everything isn't lining up right. The offset becomes more off the further down it is.

Could this be a problem with converting dp to pixels on different phones? Has anyone else encountered the same problem as me with other phones and if that is the case how did you solve it?

The function converting dp to px looks like following:

```
@JvmOverloads @Dimension(unit = Dimension.PX) fun Number.dpToPx(
    metrics: DisplayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
): Float {
    return toFloat() * metrics.density
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar problem, problem was dpToPx() not rounding the number correctly. I simply just rounded the converted number after it was calculated, solved the problem